# Can we enhance the volume in video view of android?

Tags: android

I am using video view for playing video in android but volume of the video is very low, can I enhance the volume in the code?

Thanks,
Rv

Comment: The volume in the code? as in? Is it that Video View is open source and you want to increase the maximum volume by editing the source?

Answer (score 3):

To let the user adjust the volume via the volume buttons on their device, call `setVolumeControlStream()` on your `Activity`, probably supplying a value of `AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC` as the stream to adjust.

If you wish to provide your own on-screen volume control, see the `AudioManager` class.